# Android cardview first item and last item not showing correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-cardview

[image: Cardview first item]

So I follow an Android tutorial from ude*y, everything works perfectly, the only problem is the first and last item of cardview not showing correctly.

Comment: Could you add xml of you cardview element and the code used for setup RecyclerView?

Comment: Share your XML's with us. But from what I see, your recyclerview is not bellow the toolbar. You have to set it bellow the toolbar or give it a margin top

Comment: Welcome to so,your question is too broad - please read [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please share you XML code for `CardView` and `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to margin or padding as your requirement.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/tryagain"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/no_data_available" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You want see more full card view example, please following this github:

https://github.com/dharmakshetri/CardViewExample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/main.xml

and full source code: 
 [CardViewExample](http://%20https://github.com/dharmakshetri/CardViewExample)